# How to make my selectbox overflow in my fixed footer if the browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is when mybrowser resize that the footer and my selectbox are so close the dropdown list is covered by the footer. I want the dropdown list overflow in my footer.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/31/

footer:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom myFooter" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">My Fixed Footer</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

css:

```
.myFooter { overflow: visible;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `onmousedown` and `onchange` handlers which mess with the `size` attribute and it works correctly:

```
<select name="month" lass="btn btn-default" id="bmonth">
    <option value="">Month</option>
</select>
<select name="day" class="btn btn-default" id="bday">
    <option value="">Day</option>
</select>
<select name="year" class="btn btn-default" id="byear">
    <option value="">Year</option>
</select>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/32/)

Comment: The purpose on the mousedown and onchange is to make the dropdownlist short if click.

Comment: @Rory, then how we add listeners for change/mousedown? i update your fiddle by applying event using jquery and it show same issue http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/38/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.myFooter { overflow: hidden;}
```

or/ and

```
.dateWrap { height: 32px; margin-bottom: 1.0em; }
```

instead

```
.dateWrap { height: 32px; overflow: visible; margin-bottom: 1.0em; }
```